# How to prevent getting background colored when using raycaster?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm doing simple three js scene with ground, sky, and some objects. Some objects should be colored red when mouse over, but not all. I got it work in way it colors everything red I touch but how do I prevent that, and just paint the objects i want to paint? For example not a ground, sky, or houses, but only the cars.

Is it something I should do for this line?

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

The rest of it is like:

```
for ( i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
                intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
                }
```

I'm not putting any more code in here but it's so simple that i bet you understand what i'm doing. basic geometry stuff and raycaster made based on examples from threejs.org.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern to follow if you want to raycast against a subset of the scene objects:

```
var objects = [];

...

objects.push( mesh1 );
objects.push( mesh2 );

...

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.83